# Why is my GWT app not loading sometimes?

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I have a problem with my GWT/libgdx app (GWT ver: 2.6.0, Gdx ver: 1.9.2) and I cannot find any recent solution, or something that match my issue, on the Internet. Short story is, sometimes, "randomly" (or inexplicably, to be honest), my app choose not to load on the first try (or second, third...), and then after one (or two, three) refresh, it works (... and sometimes it doesn't, at all). Sometimes it loads immediatly, too.

This behviour happens on various browser (firefox, chrome, chrome for mobile... Surprisingly enough IE is not the most problematic browser here), on various machines (and OS). So, on my Linux/firefox, I often have no problems (not always). But on my colleague Windows10/Chrome, we have to refresh the page two or three times, and on his phone (Android/Chrome) it never displays. I don't exactly know the versions.

On Firefox, I thought I had a hint first, because the blablabla.cache.html file seemed not to be loaded (in the sources page of the inspector) when the page refused to load (which would explains why, even if it would be totally not normal that this part would randomly be there or not!). But then, the .cache.html was here, and not my app...

All that I know for sure is that onModuleLoad() is never called when my app is not displayed. Neither is this part (from gdx):

```
public PreloaderCallback getPreloaderCallback() {
    return new PreloaderCallback() {

        @Override
        public void error(String file) {
            alert("error");
        }

        @Override
        public void update(PreloaderState state) {
            if (state.hasEnded()) {
                alert("loaded");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So I know that, with these weird and little pieces of information, it will be impossible to know what is wrong. But did anyone get such a curious and untrusty behaviour with a GWT and / or gdx app?

**EDIT :** I noticed two possible explanations for my problem. Now it is mostly solved but I'd like to help anyone who could have the same trouble in the future.
The first one is in the html file. It was impossible for you to know because I did not think it was a possible cause for my issue. I was using React and GWT to display my app, and both React and GWT were rendered in a unique div.

When React is rendered first, the GWT part is added in the div, so everything works well. Yet, when GWT is rendered first, the React part replace it in the div. Most of the time React was faster and I did not see any problem. The solution was easy: I added another div specifically for React.

The second issue was on iOS10. Gdx uses an old version of SoundManager2 that needs a patch to work on iOS10, and even stops the application loading. I had to use more recent sources of SM2.

Comment: Take a look at the web console. If you see messages similar to "xxx.nocache.js not found," it means the GWT-generated javascript isn't in your servlet container's working directory. If you're running from Eclipse, for example, it could be because you cleaned your project.

Comment: Perhaps you should start using Maven or Gradle when running GWT this way you will be sure that your run configuration is working every time.

Comment: TorgGor: no message of the sort, and the file is in the directory.
xybrek: I am using gradle to compileGWT my Java project (and build the war rep). Is that what you mean by "running GWT"?